# Shell How to check if a pattern exists in a line in file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, sh

How can we check if a pattern or String exists in a line at particular line number in a file:

A file has following line at line number 28:

page.sysauth = {"Admin"}

I need to check if "Admin" exists at this **particular line** ( It may or may not exists at multiple places in the entire file.)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk you can do this:

```
awk '/Admin/ && NR == 28 { print "exists" }' file
```

Or using `sed | grep`:

```
sed '28q;d' file | grep -q 'Admin' && echo "exists"
```

Comment: How can we use this in conjunction with if in shell i.e instead of echo exists. I need to check this as a condition,

Comment: `&&` is indeed a shell construct. Using `if/fi` you could do **`if sed '28q;d' file | grep -q 'Admin'l then echo "exists" else echo "nope"; fi`**

Comment: You can still use `awk` with `'/Admin/ && NR==28 { exit 0 } END {exit 1}'`.

Comment: @chepner `awk NR==28{print !/Admin/}` will do the same.  Exist 0 for success 1 for fail, or remove `!` for 1 for match 0 for no match.

Comment: @karakfa That outputs a value; it doesn't exit 1 or 0 (or rather, its exit status is not related to the presence of `Admin` on line 28). Also, it assumes the file has at least 28 lines.

Comment: @chepner: right on both accounts!  changing print to exit will solve one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Use `head` & `tail` to extract the line, then `grep` to check the presence:

```
if head -n28 file | tail -n1 | grep -q '"Admin"' ; then
    echo Present
else
    echo Not present
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

```
awk 'NR==28{print (/Admin/?"":"Not ")"present"}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '$q1;28{/Admin/q0;q1}' file && echo present || echo not present
```